# How to send params in useHistory of React Router Dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using React Router hooks for navigation `useHistory`.

Navigate :    `history.push("/home", { update: true });`

In home : I am trying to get params  `let {update} = useParams();`

But `update` is always undefined. Whats wrong with this code. Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you put little bit more code here? may be your component. that would make que more clear

Comment: already solved. I need to use `useLocation` hooks instead of `useParams `

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The second parameter in the `history.push()` method is actually known as the location state,

```
history.push(path, [state])
```

Depending on your requirements, you may want to pass `update` as part of the location state, or the query string.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  search: '?update=true',  // query string
  state: {  // location state
    update: true, 
  },
});
```

As stated on the React-Router [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location), you can access the state by accessing the `location` props. In your case, to get the value for `update`,

On class components, assuming that it is connected to the router,

```
this.props.location
```

For functional components, you can use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook to access the location object.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
const location = useLocation();

console.log(location.state.update)  // for location state
console.log(location.search)  // for query strings;
```

Comment: thank you . it helps.  I need to use `useLocation` hook instead of `useParams `

Answer (score 12):

If you are using React Hooks follow this method because **this.props**  is only available in React Class.

Component One:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const ComponentOne = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        history.push('/component-two',{params:'Hello World'})
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {handleSubmit()}}>Fire</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Component Two:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const ComponentTwo = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const myparam = location.state.params;
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{myparam}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is how you can pass

```
history.push("/home", { update: true });
```

and access like this if it's stateless component.

```
props.location.state.update;
```

if class based component.

```
this.props.location.update;
```

Comment: Hash history does not support `location.update` anymore, It moved to `location.state.update `

Answer (score 1):

There's also a simpler way to access the state passed on if you're using functional components:

First, pass in the state in history.push

```
history = useHistory();
history.push('/path-to-component-2', 'state')
```

Next, u can retrieve the state in the location props

```
const Component2 = ({ location }) => {
  console.log(location.state);
  return null;
};
```