# TSX child component value undefined

Tags: typescript, tsx

In my application I have a table of projects that when I click on any of the rows with an "Error" status message, it should reroute the user to an ErrorsPage that gives a detailed error stacktrace about what's causing the error. Inside of my project table file, I have this function where I'm passing projectScanID to ErrorsPage as a prop:

```
const handleClickOnTableRow = (projectScanID: number, scanStatus: string) => {
        if (scanStatus === 'Completed') {
            history.push(`/results/${projectScanID}`);
        }

        if (scanStatus === 'Error') {
            console.log(projectScanID);
            <ErrorsPage
                project_id={projectScanID}
            />
            history.push(`/error`);
        }
    }
```

Notice console.log right before I pass project_id to the ErrorsPage. This console.log prints an int. Then, history.push reroutes the webpage to the ErrorsPage which looks like this:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {useFetchErrors} from "../Api/Api";

interface ExecutionTableProps {
  project_id: number
}

const ErrorsPage: React.FC<ExecutionTableProps> = ({project_id}) => {
    console.log(project_id)
    const errors = useFetchErrors(project_id)
    return(
        <h1>fj</h1>
    )
}
export default ErrorsPage;
```

It says project_id is undefined on the first line under the ErrorsPage functional component.
What is causing this issue? Am I incorrectly passing project_id to ErrorsPage as a prop? All I know for sure is that it's being routed to the correct page, as it says project_id is undefined on the first line of ErrorsPage.

Comment: You never actually render `ErrorsPage` by `return`ing it. Did you mean to pass it into the `history.push`?

Comment: you are using  history.push(`/error`) for navigation to ErrorsPage, don't create  <ErrorsPage in handle, Navigate to /error route and pass the value through state like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464337/how-to-send-params-in-usehistory-of-react-router-dom